# Scraping dynamic data

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am scraping profiles on ask.fm for a research question. The problem is that only the top most recent questions are viewable and I have to click "view more" to see the next 15.

The source code for clicking view more looks like this:

```
<input class="submit-button-more submit-button-more-active" name="commit" onclick="return Forms.More.allowSubmit(this)" type="submit" value="View more" />
```

What is an easy way of calling this 4 times before scraping it. I want the most recent 60 posts on the site. Python is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

**Without using Headless Browser**

1. Open the chrome debugger tools -> Network Tab.
2. Now click on the View More button.
3. Inspect the request being fired in the Network dialog when you click on View More.
4. The data would be loaded from an external API in most cases so check whether the request to the API is a get or a post request and the kind of response from it.
5. There could be a limit or any similar query parameter which could be passed to that url so as to limit the no of response objects. In your case, it would be 15.
6. Try to make the request to the same URL from your script increasing the limit to 60 let's say and check the response.
7. The above technique works in most cases. But if this doesn't work for you try the following steps.

**Using Headless Browser**

1. Try to use a headless browser which loads the dynamic content, you have the methods to scroll down, click etc available.
2. Examples of Headless browsers are Selenium, Splash, PhantomJS, SlimmerJS etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use selenium to browse to the website and click on the button/link a few times. You can get that here:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Or you might be able to do it with mechanize:

- http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

I have also heard good things about twill, but never used it myself:

- http://twill.idyll.org/